# Time difference between current time and timestamp+milliseconds

Tags: php, mysql

I'm wanting to display on a php page the difference between the current server time and a datetime row plus a row that has milliseconds in it, so I guess the equation would look kind of like ((Datetime+Milliseconds)-Server Time).

The only problem is, I'm not sure how to do it in code. I can currently get the difference between the datetime row and the current time with `echo strtotime($row['date_added']) - time();` When I try adding the row that contains the milliseconds, `date_mil`, I get a really long number.

The date in the row `date_added` looks like `2012-05-25 16:55:06` and the value of the `date_mil` is around `218238`.

I'm still learning how to do all of this, and this has me confused. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Aren't those milliseconds microseconds?  If you want to add those just divide the number of microseconds by 10^6 or 1 000 000 and add them where appropriate.

Comment: They are milliseconds, in the example above it's about 218 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my own problem.

```
$difference = time() - strtotime($row['date_added']);
$milliseconds = round(($row['date_mil']) * .001);
echo $milliseconds - $difference;
```